Does anyone have a resolution for this: metadata is inconsistent error when restoring a backed up database to a higher level SQL server
The corruption does not appear to be in the user data tables but in the internal database system tables.  However, when the database is restored, because a system table is corrupt, the database is not in a completely recovered state.  This prevents some of the upgrade steps from completing.  That means your data looks to be intact, but database can’t be upgraded.

They did run DBCC CHECKDB on the server that the backup came from and got the same error.  They did not restore the database to the same version/edition as the source. We do have a DBA now looking at this for us.

Please add your RESTORE command. You can script it from the restore GUI, if you are using the GUI.
To me, the error message look like you specify parts of the database to restore, syntax structure something like:
RESTORE DATABASE myDatabase
FILE = y
FROM DISK = ...
...

Above is in a rare thing to do. The use case is that you have a database where a part of the database is broken (one of the database files) and you want to restore only that part. (And then roll forward to current time by restoring an unbroken chain of log backups until "now".)
But what you are doing now is trying to upgrade the database, which would be difficult (or perhaps not even possible) if you restore it part-by-part. SQL server can't have some of the database as the old version and some as the new version.
My guess is that you are using the FILE option by mistake, and instead should be using the following syntax structure:
RESTORE DATABASE myDatabase
FROM DISK = ...
...

